# Order <form:error path="*"/> messages so their order isn't random

Tags: spring, hibernate-validator

When I do a `<form:errors path="*"/>` my errors are always shown in a random order.
Now I was wondering how I could display them in a set order.

What I mean with random is:
fields: field1, field2, field3
output 1: field2, field1, field3
output 2: field 3, field 2, field 1
...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact fit to your question.
You can order your errors if you specify the desired path value instead of "*".
For example,

```
<form:errors path="field1"/>
<form:errors path="field2"/>
<form:errors path="field3"/>
```

Comment: That's how I'm doing it for now. But it would be nice to be capable to just do path="*".